# ofstream and fprintf both limits files to print only 5 lines of data

Tags: c++, printf, line, limit, ofstream

I need to print a world file containing 6 lines of data. If I print 6 lines of one field each, nothing happens. If I print only 5 lines, data comes out correct, but the last line contains two fields of data.
This does work when I remove one << endl

```
double ResEast = 0.05;
double ResNorth = -0.05;
double UTMMinEast = 459947.750;
double UTMMaxNorth = 7564825.450;
std::ofstream outputfile;
outputfile.open(worldoutname, std::ofstream::out);
outputfile << std::setprecision(12);
if (outputfile.is_open()) {

    outputfile << ResEast << endl;
    outputfile << "0.0" << endl;
    outputfile << "0.0" << endl;
    outputfile << ResNorth << endl;
    outputfile << UTMMinEast << "  " ;
    outputfile << UTMMaxNorth << endl;
    outputfile.close();
}

else
{
    std::cerr << "didn't write" << std::endl;
}
```

this code will give no file written at all. Nothing happens.

```
double ResEast = 0.05;
double ResNorth = -0.05;
double UTMMinEast = 459947.750;
double UTMMaxNorth = 7564825.450;

std::ofstream outputfile;
outputfile.open(worldoutname, std::ofstream::out);
outputfile << std::setprecision(12);
if (outputfile.is_open()) {

    outputfile << ResEast << endl;
    outputfile << "0.0" << endl;
    outputfile << "0.0" << endl;
    outputfile << ResNorth << endl;
    outputfile << UTMMinEast << endl;
    outputfile << UTMMaxNorth << endl;
    outputfile.close();
}

else
{
    std::cerr << "didn't write" << std::endl;
}
```

I tried the same with fprintf and the same problem comes up. this solution works with two fields written to the same last line:

```
FILE* pFile;
const int length = worldoutname.length();
// declaring character array (+1 for null terminator)
char* char_array = new char[length + 1];
// copying the contents of the
// string to char array
strcpy(char_array, worldoutname.c_str());
fopen_s(&pFile,char_array,"w");

double ResEast = 0.05;
double ResNorth = -0.05;
double UTMMinEast = 459947.750;
double UTMMaxNorth = 7564825.450;

fprintf_s(pFile, "%f\n0.0\n0.0\n%f\n%f %f\n", ResEast, ResNorth, UTMMinEast, UTMMaxNorth);
fclose(pFile);
```

This solution gives no file written. The only difference is the \n between the last two fields:

```
FILE* pFile;
const int length = worldoutname.length();
// declaring character array (+1 for null terminator)
char* char_array = new char[length + 1];
// copying the contents of the
// string to char array
strcpy(char_array, worldoutname.c_str());
fopen_s(&pFile,char_array,"w");

double ResEast = 0.05;
double ResNorth = -0.05;
double UTMMinEast = 459947.750;
double UTMMaxNorth = 7564825.450;

fprintf_s(pFile, "%f\n0.0\n0.0\n%f\n%f\n%f\n", ResEast, ResNorth, UTMMinEast, UTMMaxNorth);
fclose(pFile);
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: How can you know that no file has been written? In the first version, you should see an error message. **But** if you do not use an absolute path, the file is created *relatively to the current working directory*. And in most IDE, that directory is not what beginners expect... How to fix: pass an absolute path.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/Kvvn1sP5z)

Comment: I will try to use a debugger and see if it gives me a solution. The problem is that this is part of a large program using CUDA. 
I know that the file is not written since it is written when I remove one line (\n) or 'endl'. the path is the same.

Comment: As you can see in my example, there's no problem writing the file like you do. There's something else going on in your program preventing the file from being written.

Comment: Tangential: don't abuse `std::endl` when `"\n"` will do.  `std::endl` flushes the output stream every time you call it and this impacts performance.

Comment: I appreciate very much Teds comment. There must be some limitations in VS 2019 or somewhere else that prevents to write one line feed. since I can write all data ok, it is only the line feed that is the difference. As we all know working with software, the problem can be something very odd.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `std::ofstream outputfile; outputfile.open(worldoutname, std::ofstream::out);` to `std::ofstream outputfile(worldoutname);` (I also removed the redundant `std::ifstream::out`).

Answer (score 0):

I did what Quimby suggested and went through the program step by step. I found that some code actually deleted the file afterwards, but not if I removed one line feed. Bugs like that are difficult to track. So the code works well, the problem was other place. Still it is not sure why this extra line feed could delete the file.

One problem is that use of debugging in VS 2019 + CUDA, is that CUDA does not produce the images in debug mode. Things take too long time. Release mode is normally used to verify that things work. This was not a CUDA problem so debug mode showed me the problem.

The tip with use of \n instead of endl was nice. Thanks to everyone for helping me.

Comment: Minor point: in C and C++ `'\n'` is a newline, not a line feed. It’s the same value as an ASCII line feed, but its job is to do whatever is needed to start a new line. On Windows that means sending a carriage return and a line feed to the console. On other systems it only needs to send a single character.